# Seeking Efficient Solution for Determinant Calculation of a Complex $5\times 5$ Matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant

I recently encountered a challenging determinant problem in an Olympiad Exam (BdJSO) and have been struggling to find an efficient solution. The matrix in question is:

> $A=\begin{vmatrix}
> 3 & 0 & 0 & -2 & 4 \\
> 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> 0 & -1 & 0 & 5 & -3 \\
> -4 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 6 \\
> 0 & -1 & 0 & 3 & 2 \\
> \end{vmatrix}$;  Find the value of $A$

I have attempted to compute the determinant using traditional methods, but the complexity of the matrix has made the process quite intricate. According to a simulator, the result is $-114$, but I am eager to understand the steps involved in reaching this solution or any shortcut or determinant property that can be applied.

Could someone kindly provide insights into a **more efficient** *or* **shortcut** approach to compute the determinant of this specific $5$$\times$$5$ matrix? Any explanations, hints, or alternative methods would be greatly appreciated.

*Thank you in advance for your assistance!*

Comment: Expand along the third column, it becomes a $4\times 4$... :)

Comment: And the second row

Comment: @user619894 And then it becomes a $3\times 3$ which is (I guess) manageable... There might be more tricks to make it even easier :)

Comment: @Nothingspecial

 Yes, It's perfect...
Your hints were incredibly helpful, and I appreciate the clarity and efficiency in your explanation. It has significantly enhanced my understanding of determinants. Kudos for your assistance!

Comment: @RaihanSarker I can't tell if you are being sarcastic. Expanding a determinant along rows or columns which have abundant zeroes is a very common approach in simplification. I'll try to write an answer with more details or link some resources.

Comment: @Nothingspecial sorry to bother...I'm just a beginner in matrix

Comment: @RaihanSarker no worries. At the end, you will be surprised how easy it is!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe by "traditional methods", you mean expanding along the first row.

The main idea is that we can expand a determinant along any row/column we want and arrive at the correct answer.

For the ease of computation, we choose to expand along rows/columns which have abundant zeroes.

$A=\begin{vmatrix}
3 & 0 & \color{red}{0} & -2 & 4 \\
0 & 2 & \color{red} 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & \color{red} 0 & 5 & -3 \\
-4 & 0 & \color{red} 1 & 0 & 6 \\
0 & -1 & \color{red} 0 & 3 & 2 \\
\end{vmatrix}$

Expanding along the third column... You ignore the zeroes and get to the only non-zero entry i.e., $a_{43}=1$ and extract its minor by "removing" the fourth row and the third column.

$A=1\times (-1)^{4+3}\cdot \begin{vmatrix}
3 & 0  & -2 & 4 \\
\color{red}0 & \color{red}2  & \color{red}0 & \color{red}0 \\
0 & -1   & 5 & -3 \\
0 & -1  & 3 & 2 \\
\end{vmatrix}$

I'll add explanation about the factor $1\times (-1)^{4+3}$ if you want.

Now continue this process choosing the second row.

$A=1\times (-1)^{4+3}\times 2\times (-1)^{2+2}\cdot \begin{vmatrix}
3  & -2 & 4 \\
0    & 5 & -3 \\
0   & 3 & 2 \\
\end{vmatrix}$

Repeat this exercise, expanding along the first column.

$A=1\times (-1)^{4+3}\times 2\times (-1)^{2+2}\times 3\times (-1)^{1+1}\cdot \begin{vmatrix}
 5 & -3 \\
 3 & 2 \\
\end{vmatrix}$